# Merging socket request/response in a function

Tags: c#, sockets, mono

I'm trying to implement a client/server application communicating through sockets. The communication works fine and I can match and execute different functions. Most of the packets are from request / response type and are matched with a persistent sequence number.

The problem I'm now stating is that I can't lead back the response to the method initially sending the request. I would like to achieve this to make the overall usage simpler.

Here's a sequence diagram of the request/response communication:
[Communication sample](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/cgi-bin/cdraw?lz=dGl0bGUgUmVxdWVzdC9SZXNwb25zZSBtYXRjaGluZwoKQ2xpZW50LT4rU2VydmVyOiBBdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbgAzCCwgc2VxdWVuY2VpZDogMQoKACkGLT4AOgY6IFNvbWUgb3RoZXIgcGFja2V0cwpub3RlIHJpZ2h0IG9mIABYCABiBiBjb3VsZCBzZW5kIG11bHRpcGxlADEIIGluXG50aGUgbWVhbnRpbWUgd2l0aCBubyBhc3NvY2kAgRMGXG50byB0aGUgaW5pdGlhbCByAIFfBiAAgRMILT4tAIEVCACBQxEAggEGAIFEEQ&s=napkin)

**This is my current (not working) approach:**

The initiating function call:

```
public bool Login(string username, string password) {
    bool success = State.Send(new LoginPacket(username, password));
    return success;
}
```

State is the communication object with the open socket and the send/receive functions.

After the answer is received, the Send-method returns the value from the response.

The Send and HandleReceive method of the State-object:

```
public virtual T Send<T>(RequestResponsePacket<T> sp) {
    ...

        try {
            m_Socket.BeginSend (buffer, 0, length, SocketFlags.None, m_OnSend, m_Socket);
            m_SendDone.WaitOne ();
            Promise<T> promise = new Promise<T> ();
            m_UnansweredRequests.Add (sequenceNr, promise);

            promise.ResetEvent.WaitOne ();

            sp.OnSend ();
            return promise.ReturnValue;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            TraceException (ex);
            Dispose (false);
        }
    ...
}

public bool HandleReceive() {
        ByteQueue buffer = Buffer;

        ...
            ushort reqid = buffer.GetRequestID ();
            Promise<?> p;//Doesn't work
            m_UnansweredRequests.TryGetValue (reqid, out promise);

            if (promise != null) {
                promise.ReturnValue = buffer.GetReturnValue();
                promise.ResetEvent.Set ();
            }
        ...
    }
```

The Promise class:

```
public class Promise<T>
{
    private ManualResetEvent m_ResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent (false);
    private T m_ReturnValue {get; set;}
}
```

My problem with this approach is, that I cannot store the Promisses in a Dictionary because they are from different types:

```
    private Dictionary<ushort, Promise<?>> m_UnansweredPackets; //Doesn't work
```

Is there another approach to achieve my goal? Do I miss something?

Comment: Why are you using asynchronous API when you're just blocking right after that? And why aren't you using `Task<T>`? Ideally with `await` to make it really simple. Also, you should really add the unanswered request *before* sending the message - while it's almost impossible to have the response fast enough to matter usually, it's still a dangerous practice.

Comment: @luaan Thanks for your advice to add the request before sending. The reason I'm not using Tasks is, that mono is the target environment of the client and is currently not supporting this implementation. [Mono compatibility](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/)

Comment: Umm, I'm not sure you're reading that correctly. As I read it, Mono supports both `Task` and `await` (the two *are* separate - .NET 4.0 added `Task`, while 4.5 (with C# 5) added `await`), in fact. As long as you're using a Mono version recent enough, you should be fine (which basically means unless you're using Unity3D :D).

Comment: @luaan I thought it's the same and for this reason haven't tried it yet :-/ Thank you for correcting me, now I'm receptive to use Tasks :-)
Have you some links or could you give me a hint how such an implementation would look like?

Comment: On the surface, it's extremely simple - most asynchronous APIs simply return a task that you can `await` (if available) or bind with a continuation (similar to the callbacks you're using now) manually. Or, if you really want, you can wait on them synchronously the same way you're using `ManualResetEvent`s now. If you want to create manual tasks, you just use `TaskCompletionSource`, which allows you to set the result at will, while also getting a `Task` that you can use as usual. But you still need to think a bit different from Java in certain things, like generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to ignore the generic parameter when adding the `Promise` to the dictionary. This can easily be done by either inheritance or interfaces, depending on your needs (for example, `Task<T>` inherits from `Task`). Unlike Java, you can't simply use `Promise<?>` like you're trying to.

For example:

```
public interface IPromise
{
    void Complete(ByteQueue data);
}

public class Promise<T> : IPromise
{
    public ManualResetEvent ResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent (false);
    public T ReturnValue {get; private set;}

    private object syncObject = new object();

    public void Complete(ByteQueue data)
    {
        ReturnValue = data.GetReturnValue();
        ResetEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

Which allows you to just use `IPromise` in the dictionary, and call `Complete(buffer)` when you're receiving the response, without knowing anything about the real types.

But still, you probably want to use `Task`s instead of your own class. They're pretty flexible, and allow you to use asynchronous code quite easily - not to mention they handle the synchronization for you properly; the code I've shown actually *isn't* entirely thread-safe. It's not exactly easy making it entirely safe - just stick to `Task`s, they already have all this handled safely.